# CSS image not changing after editing css file

Tags: css, joomla

I have an css file on a Joomla site containing SSIs, which is the only css file the site includes. It's looking like this:

```
<!--#include file="style1.css" -->
<!--#include file="style2.css" -->
<!--#include file="style3.css" -->
```

So I needed to make style3 dynamic to change a picture depending on the current date, so "style3.css" is now "style3.css.php".
But when calling the site, the old image of the non-dynamic stylesheet is displayed. Only after clearing the cache it's displayed right.

Is it possible to make the image visible whithout having to clear the browser cache? Do I have to set any no-cache headers?

Comment: Dont know if this is possible in joomla, but try style3.css.php?version=TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS. Remember that this will FORCE user to download this style every time even if it is not changed. You should try to do such a things in JQuery, and leave CSS alone... Good luck :).

Comment: thanks, but then I would have to also change the SSI css file to a .css.php

Comment: is there a possibility whithout that?